# NavigationProperty has wrong data

Tags: breeze

I have a very simple example I am trying to set up with the following schema...

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomethingVeryBig { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to test is using Breeze in a way disconnected from my data repository, so I am hand coding from the Fluent API my DBContext.  Context code below, "FoosDb" is just an sdf file deployed with the project for the Breeze Metadata and is not a real database we are saving data into.

```
public class FoosDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FoosDbContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "FoosDb")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<FoosDbContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Link> Links { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasKey(f => f.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasKey(b => b.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(f => f.Bars).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(b => b.FooId);
    }
}

public class FoosContextProvider : EFContextProvider<FoosDbContext>
{
    public FoosContextProvider() : base() { }

    protected override List<KeyMapping> SaveChangesCore(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
        return new List<KeyMapping>();
    }

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
    {
        // return a map of those entities we want saved.
        return saveMap;
    }
}
```

Everything works great and I am testing all CRUD operations via a project from the Hot Towel Template, but when I query Foos from my controller the json data looks perfect, but when it gets transferred to Breeze/Knockout Observables the data in each "Foo.Bars" list is wrong.  It is taking Bar.Id = 1 and always putting that on Foo.Id = 1, Bar.Id = 2 and putting that on Foo.Id = 2, and so on.  Even though in my example Bar.Id = 2 should be on Foo.Id = 1.

Comment: Can you provide a small solution reproducing the problem? Send it to breeze@ideablade.com. Thanks.

Comment: any luck on this? Hate to be a pest but it is holding up two of my projects right now.  We are open to buying a block of support hours if that would make things go a bit quicker.

Comment: @marc, I can't make much sense of the sample you sent. I run it and in the main screen (i.e. Parent1/View1) I see the Foos you created and returned by "BuildFoos", but I don't see you trying to bring Bars into the client anywhere. (I don't even see an IQueryable<Bar> Bars() defined in the controller. If I understood correctly, the issue you described is that the navigation entities (i.e. Bars) were not being correctly resolved back in the client on Breeze/Knockout Observables. However, in your sample I don't even see Bars being brought to the client. Please clarify.

Comment: sbelini thanks for responding!  I just sent some more information to the ideablade.com inbox.  Basically there is no method on the controller to retrieve "Bars".  When I query "Foos" I should get the bars via Foo.Bars on the object model.  Bars are definitely coming down to the client and bound to the view, but the "Bars" are not being associated to the correct "Foos".  You will see it in the screen shots.  Thanks!

Comment: Well I have been trying to get it to work with .expand('Bars') and that is not working either.  On the service I added .Include("Bars") which made me add some extension methods but even after adding the extension methods I still get the following error back from the service.

Comment: System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<SpaPoc.Models.Foo>' does not contain a definition for 'Include'

Comment: at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )\r\n   
  at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass11.<ApplyExpand>b__e(String expand)\r\n   
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)\r\n   
  at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplyExpand(IQueryable queryable, String expandsQueryString)\r\n   
  at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplySelectAndExpand(IQueryable queryable, NameValueCollection map)\r\n   
  at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   ...

Comment: am I trying to do something that the Framework is just not designed to handle.  It seems like it just does not work real well when it is not fully connected to a database

Comment: @marc, I think the issue is that your objects are not being recognized as entities. It might have to do with the client not getting the metadata. I'll confirm and let you know.

Comment: @sbelini this issue is fixed, all we had to do on the Bar object have both the FooId and an instance of Foo, and it works.  What is weird is we do not even have to set the Foo instance (it can be null) and it automatically works